# Подключение FarseerPhysics

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

Возникла необходимость в подключении физического движка, выбрал Farseer Physics
Делаю по [видео](https://youtu.be/MV0FvcSLKrM)
При сборке появляется ошибка:
`Ошибка CS0006  Не удалось найти файл метаданных "D:\Andrew\Programs\Farseer Physics Engine 3.5 Samples\Farseer Physics Engine 3.5\bin\WindowsGL\Debug\FarseerPhysics MonoGame.dll`
Проверил папку, там и правда нет `FarseerPhysics MonoGame.dll`
Никто не сталкивался? Не знаю как исправить ошибку, ибо без понятия где брать этот файл
P.S.: Скачивал Farseer Physics с [официального сайта](https://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй так

http://alangamedev.com/farseer-physics-on-visual-studio-2015-monogame/

Чтобы исправить это, разверните все «Ссылки» из всех проектов и удалите MonoGame.Framework (щелкните правой кнопкой мыши и выберите «Удалить»)

Теперь добавьте их, указав на правильный ресурс, сделайте это, щелкните правой кнопкой мыши по «Ссылки» и выберите «Добавить ссылку», затем в появившемся диалоговом окне просмотрите правильную сборку MonoGame, в моем случае она находится в каталоге установки по умолчанию (C:\Program Files (x86)\MonoGame\v3.0\Assemblies\Windows)

Если вы попытаетесь запустить его сейчас, вы получите ошибки в отношении используемой версии .NET Framework, чтобы исправить это, щелкнуть правой кнопкой мыши по всем проектам, выбрать «Свойства» и на появившейся вкладке настроек выбрать Новой .NET Framework (я выбрал 4.5).

Теперь, если вы попытаетесь запустить его, он будет жаловаться на SDL, этот легко исправить, щелкните правой кнопкой мыши на SDL.dll и удалите его тоже: